# pymongo, mongodb add a new key to an existing dictionary

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How to update a dicitonary element of a record to add a new key if not exist or update the corresponding value of the key, if it exists.
For example:

```
record = {'_id':1,
            'value': {'key1' : '200'}}
```

I wish to update the `'value'` by adding a new key-value pair. e.g.  `value={'key2':'300'}`. So my desired updated record would be:

```
    record = {'_id':1,
                'value': {'key1' : '200',
                          'key2' : '300'}}
```

I've tried:

```
    value={'key2':'300'}
    mongo.db['mydb'].update(
            {'_id': 1},
            {'$set': {'value': value}})
```

But it overwrites the 'value' and does not add the new key to it:

```
record = {'_id':1,
            'value': {'key2' : '300'}}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)

```
In [20]: col.find_one()
Out[20]: {'_id': 1, 'value': {'key1': '200'}}

In [21]: col.update({'_id': 1}, {'$set': {'value.key2': 300}})
Out[21]: {'n': 1, 'nModified': 1, 'ok': 1, 'updatedExisting': True}

In [22]: col.find_one()
Out[22]: {'_id': 1, 'value': {'key1': '200', 'key2': 300}}
```

---

EDIT

If your key is in variable all you need is concatenation:

```
In [37]: key2 = 'new_key'

In [38]: col.update({'_id': 1}, {'$set': {'value.' + key2: 'blah'}})
Out[38]: {'n': 1, 'nModified': 1, 'ok': 1, 'updatedExisting': True}

In [39]: col.find_one()
Out[39]: {'_id': 1, 'value': {'key1': '200', 'new_key': 'blah'}}
```